# This app isn't compatible with your device

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I have developed an app with

```
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

and the app is installed on devices like micromax, motoe, motog, with different versions like 4.1, 4.2, 5.0, 6.0.
But when I tried with Asus phone with kitkat version, it shows **This app is not compatible with your phone**.

I don't understand what actually is going on.
Can anyone show me I am wrong?

Comment: can you post your requested permissions from the manifest?

Comment: check android lint for compatibility issues

Comment: <manifest
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="news.balarcsoft.com.news" >
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
           <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
          
        </manifest>
    
        Here I have removed the GCM Broadcast receiver and also I am using crash reporting.

Comment: @gj_ I have added the my permissions list when i try to edit my question it is giving me error ,so i have commented here

Answer (score 3):

Which Asus phone is it?

Your AndroidManifest.xml might be demanding a certain piece of hardware that is not present on that particular phone like bluetooth, nfc, telephony, wifi, etc.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: But i am not using the bluetooth or any other hardware devices.

Comment: Do you have any <compatible-screens> in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: No veerner I haven't used that

Comment: Which Asus phone is it?  Does it have Google Play services installed?

Comment: yes,it has google play.But i didnot see about the google play services

Comment: In Settings>Apps>Google Play Services, try force stop/clear data on Google Play Services, make sure a Google account is associated with the phone when you go into Gmail and Google Play.

Comment: should i enable it again

Comment: Is the phone in your posession?  Are you trying to install it by running the APK or downloading it from Google Play?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108127/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-veener).

Comment: i am trying to install it by running the APK

Comment: for camera related issues, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319532/google-play-says-that-my-app-is-not-supported-on-my-device