# Google Play says that my app is not supported on my device

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

My own app works fine on my devices if I install it manually. And on my Nexus 7 (2012) (Android 5.1.1). But when I try to install it from Google Play it says that my device is not supported. I checked AndroidManifest.xml, looked at the apk via **aapt dump badging**, added  to the manifest file but nothing helped. I have no ideas why Google Play thinks that my app is not supported.

On other my devices my app can be installed without problems: Samsung Galaxy Ace (Android 2.3), Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2), Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3), Alcatel Pixi 4 (Android 6). Any suggestions?

That's my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.proghouse.robocam

That's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.proghouse.robocam">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".HttpServer"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".GlobalSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_global_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ServerSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_server_settings"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RobotSettingsListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_robot_settings_list"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EV3SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ev3_settings"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That's what **aapt dump badging** says about my apk:

```
package: name='ru.proghouse.robocam' versionCode='4' versionName='1.0.a5' platformBuildVersionName=''
sdkVersion:'9'
targetSdkVersion:'24'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
application-label-af:'RoboCam'
application-label-am:'RoboCam'
application-label-ar:'RoboCam'
application-label-az:'RoboCam'
application-label-az-AZ:'RoboCam'
application-label-be:'RoboCam'
application-label-be-BY:'RoboCam'
application-label-bg:'RoboCam'
application-label-bn:'RoboCam'
application-label-bn-BD:'RoboCam'
application-label-bs:'RoboCam'
application-label-bs-BA:'RoboCam'
application-label-ca:'RoboCam'
application-label-cs:'RoboCam'
application-label-da:'RoboCam'
application-label-de:'RoboCam'
application-label-el:'RoboCam'
application-label-en-AU:'RoboCam'
application-label-en-GB:'RoboCam'
application-label-en-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-es:'RoboCam'
application-label-es-US:'RoboCam'
application-label-et:'RoboCam'
application-label-et-EE:'RoboCam'
application-label-eu:'RoboCam'
application-label-eu-ES:'RoboCam'
application-label-fa:'RoboCam'
application-label-fi:'RoboCam'
application-label-fr:'RoboCam'
application-label-fr-CA:'RoboCam'
application-label-gl:'RoboCam'
application-label-gl-ES:'RoboCam'
application-label-gu:'RoboCam'
application-label-gu-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-hi:'RoboCam'
application-label-hr:'RoboCam'
application-label-hu:'RoboCam'
application-label-hy:'RoboCam'
application-label-hy-AM:'RoboCam'
application-label-in:'RoboCam'
application-label-is:'RoboCam'
application-label-is-IS:'RoboCam'
application-label-it:'RoboCam'
application-label-iw:'RoboCam'
application-label-ja:'RoboCam'
application-label-ka:'RoboCam'
application-label-ka-GE:'RoboCam'
application-label-kk:'RoboCam'
application-label-kk-KZ:'RoboCam'
application-label-km:'RoboCam'
application-label-km-KH:'RoboCam'
application-label-kn:'RoboCam'
application-label-kn-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-ko:'RoboCam'
application-label-ky:'RoboCam'
application-label-ky-KG:'RoboCam'
application-label-lo:'RoboCam'
application-label-lo-LA:'RoboCam'
application-label-lt:'RoboCam'
application-label-lv:'RoboCam'
application-label-mk:'RoboCam'
application-label-mk-MK:'RoboCam'
application-label-ml:'RoboCam'
application-label-ml-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-mn:'RoboCam'
application-label-mn-MN:'RoboCam'
application-label-mr:'RoboCam'
application-label-mr-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-ms:'RoboCam'
application-label-ms-MY:'RoboCam'
application-label-my:'RoboCam'
application-label-my-MM:'RoboCam'
application-label-nb:'RoboCam'
application-label-ne:'RoboCam'
application-label-ne-NP:'RoboCam'
application-label-nl:'RoboCam'
application-label-pa:'RoboCam'
application-label-pa-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-pl:'RoboCam'
application-label-pt:'RoboCam'
application-label-pt-BR:'RoboCam'
application-label-pt-PT:'RoboCam'
application-label-ro:'RoboCam'
application-label-ru:'RoboCam'
application-label-si:'RoboCam'
application-label-si-LK:'RoboCam'
application-label-sk:'RoboCam'
application-label-sl:'RoboCam'
application-label-sq:'RoboCam'
application-label-sq-AL:'RoboCam'
application-label-sr:'RoboCam'
application-label-sr-Latn:'RoboCam'
application-label-sv:'RoboCam'
application-label-sw:'RoboCam'
application-label-ta:'RoboCam'
application-label-ta-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-te:'RoboCam'
application-label-te-IN:'RoboCam'
application-label-th:'RoboCam'
application-label-tl:'RoboCam'
application-label-tr:'RoboCam'
application-label-uk:'RoboCam'
application-label-ur:'RoboCam'
application-label-ur-PK:'RoboCam'
application-label-uz:'RoboCam'
application-label-uz-UZ:'RoboCam'
application-label-vi:'RoboCam'
application-label-zh-CN:'RoboCam'
application-label-zh-HK:'RoboCam'
application-label-zh-TW:'RoboCam'
application-label-zu:'RoboCam'
application-icon-120:'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-213:'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-640:'res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='RoboCam' icon='res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='ru.proghouse.robocam.MainActivity'  label='RoboCam' i
con=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth' reason='requested andr
oid.permission.BLUETOOTH permission, requested android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMI
N permission, and targetSdkVersion > 4'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.camera' reason='requested android
.permission.CAMERA permission'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default featur
e for all apps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi' reason='requested android.p
ermission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: 'af' 'am' 'ar' 'az' 'az-AZ' 'be' 'be-BY' 'bg' 'bn' 'bn-BD' 'bs' 'bs-BA'
 'ca' 'cs' 'da' 'de' 'el' 'en-AU' 'en-GB' 'en-IN' 'es' 'es-US' 'et' 'et-EE' 'eu'
 'eu-ES' 'fa' 'fi' 'fr' 'fr-CA' 'gl' 'gl-ES' 'gu' 'gu-IN' 'hi' 'hr' 'hu' 'hy' 'h
y-AM' 'in' 'is' 'is-IS' 'it' 'iw' 'ja' 'ka' 'ka-GE' 'kk' 'kk-KZ' 'km' 'km-KH' 'k
n' 'kn-IN' 'ko' 'ky' 'ky-KG' 'lo' 'lo-LA' 'lt' 'lv' 'mk' 'mk-MK' 'ml' 'ml-IN' 'm
n' 'mn-MN' 'mr' 'mr-IN' 'ms' 'ms-MY' 'my' 'my-MM' 'nb' 'ne' 'ne-NP' 'nl' 'pa' 'p
a-IN' 'pl' 'pt' 'pt-BR' 'pt-PT' 'ro' 'ru' 'si' 'si-LK' 'sk' 'sl' 'sq' 'sq-AL' 's
r' 'sr-Latn' 'sv' 'sw' 'ta' 'ta-IN' 'te' 'te-IN' 'th' 'tl' 'tr' 'uk' 'ur' 'ur-PK
' 'uz' 'uz-UZ' 'vi' 'zh-CN' 'zh-HK' 'zh-TW' 'zu'
densities: '120' '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640'
native-code: 'arm64-v8a' 'armeabi-v7a' 'mips' 'x86' 'x86_64'
```

Comment: Unistall your app from your device first and then try again.

Comment: I've done it many times. It does not help.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />`.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) says:

> By using this feature, an app implies that it also uses the android.hardware.camera feature, unless this parent feature is declared with android:required="false".

Because your are not declaring the parent feature `android.hardware.camera` in your manifest. The app assumes `android.hardware.camera` is needed. 
According to the documentation this feature only refers to back-facing camera's:

> The app uses the device's back-facing camera. Devices with only a front-facing camera do not list this feature, so use the android.hardware.camera.any feature instead if your app can communicate with any camera, regardless of which direction the camera faces.

Since the Nexus 7 (2012) doesn't have a backcamera, your app can't be installed from Google Play. You have to add the `android.hardware.camera.any` to your manifest to indicate your app could use a front- or backcamera as well.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: It did not help for my Nexus 7. But I found a strange thing in a supported device list: Nexus 7 grouper is supported but Nexus 7 tilapia is not (https://yadi.sk/i/vxZ11CbMuobAR). The different between them is that tilapia has a 3g and grouper is not.

Comment: One more question: do I have to add <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" /> if I use android.hardware.camera.any?

Comment: No, you don't need to add that.