# Unsupported devices in Google Play Store - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, abi

I have uploaded my app to the google store, but some of my friends are not able to install it, they get the "Your device isnt compatible with this version".

I have checked the sdk, screen sizes and permissions requirements, also uses-features required to false, and still some devices are not able to install it.

What Ive find out in the device catalog in the play console is that some models are partially supported, the supported devices have:
ABI
arm64-v8a
armeabi-v7a
armeabi

and the unsupported devices only:
armeabi-v7a
armeabi

I have developed the app with flutter, what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Your AndroidManifest.xml might be demanding a certain piece of hardware that is not present on that particular phone like bluetooth, nfc, telephony, wifi, etc  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393912/this-app-isnt-compatible-with-your-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might have set a higher minimum sdk or while generating apk armeabi-v7a armeabi is getting excluded, check app/build.gradle

change this in build.gradle

```
splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable true
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
```

**note**: this will generate 4 apks 3 for different platform and one universal

Comment: Thank you Vinil, that worked, I also had to figure out how to give each apk an unique versionCode in order to be uploaded to the google store following this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-APK-versions

Comment: Hi Vinil, should I build the apk or appbundle after setting this ?

Comment: Does this code works for aab also? I want to push the aab to playstore