# Generate android App Bundle with x86 version

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, abi, android-app-bundle

I use flutter to develop my app. However, to generate an app bundle and upload it to play console, I use Android Studio (Build -> Generate Signed Apk).

In flutter I have the option of generating three distinct apks for three architectures (arm, arm64 and x86(64?)) through flutter build commands. However when I generate signed app bundle from Android Studio and upload it play console, I only get two build variants or abi (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a). How do I make my app bundle include an x86 abi?

Additional: I only use Android Studio to generate App Bundle. I use VS Code to write these apps.

Edit: The module/App level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.spayro.spayroshop"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Can you show `build.gradle` content?

Comment: The project level or the module level?

Comment: module-level https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-split

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54937951/1891712) answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x86 architecture is not supported at this time.

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in your gradle:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

example

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Comment: NDK? Are you sure? I am not using the NDK.

Comment: Copied without attribution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56112744